# Cortana to make phone call in Android through code

Tags: cortana, cortana-intelligence, cortana-skills-kit, cortana-invoke

I would like to know on whether there is any possibility to call a phone number using cortana skill through code.

I am using microsoft web bot. I want to write code in c# for calling a person from my contacts.

I am using a luis framework, If user invokes a specific intent, i should directly call a specific phone number in my android mobile.

Is there any way i can make this call through code.?

Comment: I wonder why this question is down voted. Can you please give reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - if you want to add call functionality you have to implement it on your own because there is no ad-hoc way to invoke contacts book or make calls from Cortana.
This is also not possible currently because there is no Cortana SDK released for Android or iOS platforms to make integration. If it was there are development steps you could probably do in your mobile app source code (dedicated app because Cortana is also not integrated with mobile Android and iOS system):

1. Integrate Cortana with mobile app source code (in your case Java because of Android) which enables talking to Cortana and getting responses.
2. Implement code which handles response from the user about specific person to search in contacts book.
3. Implement code to search contacts book basing on the name of user told to Cortana.
4. Invoke platform-specific code to make call with selected number.

To sum there is no way to implement call functionality with C# and Cortana on Android (iOS neither). You can fin more information [here.](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/13/cortana-skills-kit-cortana-devices-sdk-announcement/)